# How to Enable SSL in PHP application that running on XAMPP in Windows 7?

Tags: php, ssl, xampp, windows-7

I have a few apps running on XAMPP in Windows 7 and wanted to enable SSL so I have secured connection when accessing them through the internet.

Current state:

1. My apps are running on XAMPP as web server
2. My apps are running on Windows 7
3. We can access the app with this URL: http://subdomain.domain.com:8080/myapp/

While enabling SSL on XAMPP just made it enable locally (https://localhost:8080/myapp), I wanted to enable SSL publicly instead (https://subdomain.domain.com:8080/myapp)

So, how can I made it possible to enable SSL publicly even the app running in XAMPP?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Here is a step by step solution for your case:

- Create certificate
- Config Apache to access https instead of http
- Config mod rewrite to generate SSL url
- Config Virtual host to test site

https://gist.github.com/nguyenanhtu/33aa7ffb6c36fdc110ea8624eeb51e69

Comment: thanks for quick answer. but it seems that the step above just running locally (https://localhost) instead of public as I said in question. Do you ever try it to public website?

Comment: But if you have a domain or a subdomain on it, you can put an ssl. The host provide for you or you can add a free one also... I xampp you can create a certificate in order to test the HTTPS for you... But when you want to make a public website, you need to specify that domain and configure the ssl

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. now my web app running on linux based OS. and the SSL working fine